# Is there a better way to traverse an inheritance tree?

Tags: ruby

I have a method that ascends an inheritance tree and returns the element at the root, progressively yielding the elements if appropriate:

```
# Finds the root of the hierarchy.
def root
  element = self
  until element.root?
    yield element if block_given?
    element = element.parent
  end
  yield element if block_given?
  element
end

# Walks the inheritance tree, yielding each element from self to #root.
alias until_root root
```

If I have a hierarchy like:

```
1 > 2 > 3
```

`3.root` should return `1` and `3.until_root &block` should yield `3`, then `2`, then `1`, and finally return `1`.

The line which yields elements appears twice in order to yield the actual root element, something I would've liked to accomplish *inside* the loop.

How can I improve this algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to only have one `yield` statement would be to recursion instead of a loop:

```
def root(&blk)
  yield self if blk
  if root?
    self
  else
    parent.root(&blk)
  end
end
```

Of course the usual caveats regarding recursion in ruby apply, so this isn't necessarily a good idea: It is somewhat expensive and can lead to stack overflows if you recurse deep enough (though it's rather unlikely, you'd encounter a tree deep enough to reach that limit).

---

Unrelated to this, the name `until_root` seems somewhat clunky to me. I would recommend `each_ancestor` instead. In fact I think it would be good idea to have the method return an enumerable of ancestors when no block is given. Then it could just be called `ancestors`. Of course that would require separating `ancestors` and `root` into two separate methods. `root` could then just be defined as `ancestors.last`:

```
# Returns an Enumerable containing the ancestors of this node, starting with
# the node itself and ending with the root.
# If a block is supplied, each ancestor will be yielded to the block instead
# of returning an enumerable.
def ancestors
  return enum_for(:ancestors) unless block_given?

  element = self
  until element.root?
    yield element
    element = element.parent
  end
  yield element
end

def root
  ancestors.last
end
```

If you do it that way, you can also leave out the `if block_given?` part of the `yield` statements because it will return early when no block was given.

As a matter of fact, you can now remove the second `yield` completely by changing the loop to loop while `element` is not nil instead of until the root is reached (assuming `element.parent` will return nil if the element is the root):

```
def ancestors
  return enum_for(:ancestors) unless block_given?

  element = self
  while element
    yield element
    element = element.parent
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! I'd been wondering how to return enumerators for a while. Also, just a small thought: I chose the name `until_root` because it starts from `self` and stops at `root`. If I were to use `ancestors` or `each_ancestor`, wouldn't it be inconsistent if the method yielded `self`? Should I create another method to resolve this conflict?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira Hm, you're right that `ancestors` containing `self` is a bit strange now that I think about it. Leaving the name as `until_root` might be best then.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira On second thought `ancestors` should be fine. `Class#ancestors` also includes the class itself, so there is some precedence for `ancestors` to also include the current node.

Comment: Very well. I also think `ancestors` is much clearer, but now that you mentioned `Class#ancestors`, another issue has arisen... These elements are actually classes and the root element is actually the class which initially inherited from a certain class in my library. Using that name means overriding the `Class` method. Would `each_ancestor` or `parents` be appropriate?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira In that case I'd rather call it something like `foo_ancestors` where `foo` is the name of the "certain class" you mentioned. `parents` doesn't fit because your parent's parent is not your parent.

Comment: Awesome solution, wish I could give you +10 on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it complicated overkill to return ancestors recursively in an enumerator? Each element's ancestor list seems fixed, and keeping it simple would suggest using an array.

There are duplicate `yield element` statements, unless you take the `nil` route. A nitpick, but checking for `nil` locks you into an implementation of method, `parent`. E.g., what if your class somehow in the future were to evolve into needing every element's parent to be valid? such as the parents of all roots being in an array somewhere?

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell What do you mean by every parent needing to be valid? The root by definition doesn't have a parent.

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell Regarding the enumerator being overkill: Maybe, but given that the OP also used an iterator-method instead of an array, I just stuck with that approach and just added the `enum_for` to get an enumerable.

Comment: @sepp2k, there could be many trees with their roots stored in some array, such as webpage DOM trees for browser tabs. Yet, you are probably right.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you can use `break` to remove the duplication, as below.

See also [A Wealth Of Ruby Loops And Iterators](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/a-wealth-of-ruby-loops-and-iterators/) and [Ruby Loops - while, for, until](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm).

```
# Walks the inheritance tree, remembering each element, from self to the root.
def ancestors
  result=[]
  element=self
  loop do
    result.push element
    break if element.root?
    element=element.parent
  end
  result
end

# Walks the inheritance tree, yielding at each element, from self to the root,
# returning the root.
def until_root
  a=ancestors
  a.each{|e| yield e} if block_given?
  a.last
end

# Finds the root of the hierarchy, without yielding.
def root
  ancestors.last
end
```